# How to combine two SQL date functions into one to get output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a column with the date that is the first of the month before a given date

i.e. If the date in column one is 25/01/2017, I want the date in column two to read 01/12/2016

So far, I have managed to take a month off, or reset it to the first of the month, but I can't work out a way to combine the two. Is it possible, or do I have to do it in two different statements. Here is what I have so far:

```
 SELECT 
    PAY_START_DATE,
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CONVERT(DATE,PAY_START_DATE)) AS AMMENDONE,
    DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, PAY_START_DATE), 0) AS AMMENDTWO
FROM [hronline_iTrent].[iTrent].[Payroll]
```

And this gives the output:

```
PAY_START_DATE | AMMENDONE | AMMENDTWO
2016-04-06     |06/03/2016 | 01/04/2016 00:00
2016-06-12     |12/05/2016 | 01/06/2016 00:00
```

Any chance I can combine the two so I can get an output like:

```
PAY_START_DATE | AMMEND
2016-04-06     | 2016-03-01
2016-06-12     | 2016-05-01
```

(The format of the output is not important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT  PAY_START_DATE
        ,DATEADD(DAY,1, DATEADD(MONTH,-2,EOMONTH(PAY_START_DATE)))
FROM    [hronline_iTrent].[iTrent].[Payroll]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! :)... I've accepted this one because it is the one I have ended up using but all the solutions worked. Thanks.

Comment: changed from this one to the now selected answer, because this one hasn't worked today...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select dateadd(month, -1,
               dateadd(day, 1 - day(PAY_START_DATE), PAY_START_DATE)
              )
```

The inner `dateadd()` gets the first day of the month.  The outer one subtracts one month.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair, so long as you don't mind that it's somewhat cute:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',PAY_START_DATE),'20001201')
```

It employs the fact that we pick two arbitrary dates that already have the required relationship between them that you want to achieve - I.e. `20001201` is the first of the month previous to `20010101`.